# How synchronization of threads work along with Sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class ABC extends Thread

{

    public void run()
    {
        display();
    }

    public synchronized void display()
    {
        {
            System.out.println("1");            
            try
            {
                this.sleep(1000);

            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
}

public class Thread_10 

{

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        ABC t1=new ABC();
        t1.start();
        ABC t2=new ABC();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :- 
1
1
2
2

I wanted to understand the concept of synchronization. As you can see, I have a sleep() inside  display(). Now, when thread "t1" executes run() and goes to sleep after printing "1", why does thread "t2" enters display() through run()? because, my function display() is declared synchronized, so it is already locked by thread "t1". 
I was expecting the following output:-

1
2
1
2

Comment: Someone **really** needs to read a tutorial. This shows not even a basic understanding of threading.

Comment: You're synchronizing on two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized keyword modifier before a function name basically create a thread safe block or function which will work under multi threaded environment.

> java synchronized implied on a java Object which keep the lock until current thread complete task.

for your case, you have made few mistake that you have created two different object of ABC class and started two different thread so here synchronized function does not have anything to do.it will behave just like normal function. i have modified your written classes and it will work now as synchronized.

```
ABC.java
--------       
class ABC
{
public synchronized void display()
    {
        {
            System.out.println("1");            
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
}

ExampleThread.java
------------------
public class ExampleThread extends Thread
{
  ABC abc;
  public ExampleThread(ABC a)
  {
   this.abc=a;
  }

  public void run()
  {
     while(true)
     {
      this.abc.display();
     }
  }
}

Test.java
---------
public class Test 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        ABC shared_object=new ABC();
        ExampleThread t1=new ExampleThread (shared_object);
        t1.start();

        ExampleThread t2=new ExampleThread(shared_object);
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

for more details on synchronization in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but the formatting is horrible. The only reason you don't get a down vote is due to using a fairly neat solution. In short, hit format in your IDE before posting and you may even get an up vote.

Comment: sorry. i have respond this thread very quickly. i have edited again. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are synchronizing on different objects, you need a common object. Create an Object lock field in main class synchronize on it: `sychronized(lock) {...}`